# Importing the result of a MATLAB numeric array into a new MATLAB script

Tags: arrays, matlab

Consider that I have a code that returns a double array. When run, the result returned at the command window a result looks like this:

```
mpc.gen= 

       1 100 344 34 5
       2 433 223 45 2 
       3 333 432 12 3
       4 213 233 12 3
```

What I want to do is create a MATLAB script which would contain this array. In other words in this new MATLAB script I would have the following array, constructed like this:

```
mpc.gen= [ 1 100 344 34 5 ;
           2 433 223 45 2 ;
           3 333 432 12 3 ;
           4 213 233 12 3 ;
         ] ;
```

Just calling the function would save the variable in the new script, however that is not what I need since I need to use this script for a simulation at a special power tool called MATPOWER. The array needs to be in the form shown at the new script.

The actual array is much bigger in size however I use this here for simplicity. Is there any way I can do this automatically, and not just pass the data from the command window to the new script one by one manually?

Comment: Please clarify if the answer below is what you are looking for. I'm not sure what it is that you are after. Do you want a script that has a static, constant copy of this matrix in it? Do you want to save the result of your first calculation so you can re-use it later?

Comment: Hi, I had made a mistake in the shaping of the question, as the name of the two arrays should be the same. What I want is a script that will not just store the result of the first calculation, but it will have it written analytically in this script. Hopefully this was more clarifying. Thanks for your interest. Also the dots are important for the arrays, as mpc is intentionally a struct, a pre-requisite for using the script in the MATPOWER software.

Comment: With "analytically" you mean "explicitly"? You want the computation results written as parseable text to a MATLAB script.

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html). It converts a matrix to a string representation that, when evaluated, results in the identical matrix.

For example:

```
>> result = [1 100 344 34 5;
             2 433 223 45 2;
             3 333 432 12 3;
             4 213 233 12 3];
>> mat2str(result)
ans =
   [1 100 344 34 5;2 433 223 45 2;3 333 432 12 3;4 213 233 12 3]
```

You could write this to a file like so:

```
f = fopen('test_script.m', 'w');
fprintf(f,'mpc.gen = %s\n', mat2str(result));
fclose(f);
```

The formatting is not identical to your example, but if the tool does proper MATLAB parsing, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I was not aware of `mat2str`'s existence.  Nice. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it intentional that `mpc` is a struct? (you are using dot in the name.) In the following, I use underscore instead, but it can certainly be adopted, if it is intentional.

This is what functions are for. So instead of making a script, you should create a new function. If I were to do what you want to do, I would have 2 functions and 1 script. Whereas the script looks like this

```
mpc_bus = function1;
function2(mpc_bus);
```

where `function1` is the code that returns `mpc.bus` and `function2` is the one where you want to work with `mpc.gen`, and the top would be something like this

```
function [] = function2(mpc_gen)
```

**Alternatively:** If you of some reason does not like functions, you can make the first code save the variable using `save(*filename*.mat)` and then you can load the file again in the script using `dat=load(*filename*.mat);` and `mpc_gen = dat.mpc_bus;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I accidentally had the two arrays named differently though they should have the same name. I tried to implement your attempt with the functions though it wasn't successful. Any input on how the code would now change since the two arrays will have the same name? Or is the procedure exactly the same?

Comment: The procedure is exactly the same, though the function definition in `function2` should reflect this change.

Comment: Also remember to save the two functions under the same name as you give them inside. Thus `function1` should be saved as `function1.m`.